Как можно реализовать оформление заказа с выбором товаров из определённой категории, если таблиц с товарами несколько
Хотел попросить помощи с проектом. У меня есть база с 16-ю таблицами товаров: таблица "Процессоры", где только процессоры, таблица "Материнские платы", где только они и т.д. Также есть таблица "Категории", в которой просто список категорий: те же "Материнские платы", "Процессоры" и остальные 14 наименований таблиц. В таблицах с товарами есть ячейка "IdKategory", там вводятся данные из таблицы "Категории", то есть на всех товарах таблицы "Процессоры", ячейка "IdKategory" одинаковая.
Я хотел реализовать следующий функционал:

Выбераешь категорию в ComboBox, после этого тебе дают возможность воспользоваться выбором товара из этой категории в ComboBox'е ниже. Я не могу понять, какой код и команды использовать, чтобы после выбора категории высвечивался список товаров только этой категории. Я понимаю как это сдедать, при случае, когда товары все хранятся в одной таблице и у каждого указана категория. Но как сделать это, при том, что у меня каждая категория товара - это отдельная таблица.. Я не смог сам придумать и не нашел ответа в интернете.
Хотел узнать, знает ли кто-то, как можно реализовать эту функцию, или же придется переделывать всю базу, чтобы товары были все в одной таблице (для меня это ужасное решение, даже не то, что ужасное, а невыполнимое, так как каждый товар имеет свою собственную характеристику, и сделать таблицу со всеми этими товарами, там будет большое количество не подходящих друг другу характеристик, что сделает заполнение этой таблицы просто адом)
Прилагаю следующий код:
<TextBlock Text="Категория:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" Height="20" Width="70" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

<TextBlock Text="Товар:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="3" Height="20" Width="70" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

<ComboBox x:Name="KategoryCB" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="79,10,14,10"  Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

<ComboBox x:Name="TovarCB" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="79,10,14,10"  Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

Прошу помощи, в составлении кода или хотябы предложения решения, как можно бы было это реализовать, буду благодарен! Всем мир.

У меня есть база с 16-ю таблицами товаров Лучше переделать. Одна сущность, раскиданная на 16 таблиц - это проблема.

Не ужели нет другого способа? При этом варианте, мне придется не только базу переделывать, но и приложение менять полностью... а дедлайны горят невообразимо. Но всё равноо спасибо за ответ!

Ну вот сейчас вы в такую задницу залезли с кривой архитектурой! Имена объектов (в вашем случае - таблиц) в SQL не параметризуются. А потому вместо простого запроса с параметром-категорией придётся полностью менять источник данных контрола и перезапрашивать его данные - причём всю эту ерунду либо придётся хардкодить, либо добавлять таблицы с метаданными, а то и готовыми шаблонами запросов... И чем дальше, тем будет хуже.

Сейчас вам можно разве что предложить такой вариант. Создаёте представление, в котором собираете сведения (код, имя таблицы, товар, его категория, возможно, и ещё какие-то поля) из всех 16 таблиц. И обращаетесь не к таблицам товаров, а к представлению. В этом случае фильтр по выбранной категории нормально параметризуется. Но представление будет необновляемое, потому при внесении изменений придётся в коде определять (или брать из представления) имя таблицы, и вносить изменения напрямую в таблицу.

Ох... Понял, буду пытаться, спасибо большое за помощь и советы!

При этом варианте, мне придется не только базу переделывать, но и приложение менять полностью... Вот как раз поверх единой таблицы можно создать те самые 16 представлений, каждое из которых выбирает из общей таблицы только требуемые товары. Но нужно проследить, чтобы эти представления были обновляемые. Тогда бросаться переделывать само приложение необязательно... пока во всяком случае.

Нужно логически отделить понятие "товар" от "что продаём". У каждого продаваемого объекта есть id, название, цена. Не важно, что это: проц или мать. Сделай так, чтобы таблица "товары" была связана 1 к 1 так, чтобы внешний ключ, например проца стал PK id. И да, название проца и название товара - это две разные вещи. Когда сделаешь общую таблицу, то будет легче оперировать понятием "товар". А конкретизировать его можно при просмотре (пользователь два раза кликнул на запись - открылось окно, которое отображает уже конкретизированный объект). А лучше присмотрись к postgres и его json методам.

Очень похоже на задания для по worldskills и профессионалам. Если делаете по их методичкам - печально, там практически всё неправильно. Если вам дали в колледже базу по тому, как просто привязать DatabaseContext напрямую к форме - то  это вам дают, чтобы у вас просто "заработало", в реальности такого не будет. Учите ООП (в частности к этой задаче - наследование). Посмотрите, как делается идентифицирующая связь 1 к 1 в бд. Так же присмотритесь к json. Ну и удачи с ViewModel и Binding. Так же посмотрите тему с DataTemplate в WPF. И больше никогда не относитесь серьёзно к материалам в колледже.

Ахахахаха, спасибо большое за совет, задания в колледже это всегда головная боль
